# Program crashes if mysql query is empty

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have this form that shows the unfinished transporting operations so that the manager can finish them, it ony shows the ongoing ops and if there is no ongoing ops the program crashes, i've tried to avoid this by putting a MsgBox but it didn't work. How can i make this msgbox solution work?

```
Private Sub editarops_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    conexao.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; user =root; database = frota;"
    conexao.Open()
    comando.Connection = conexao
    strsql = "SELECT codtrab, carga, origem, destino, estado, dataini FROM trabalhos where estado = 'En Route'"
    comando.Connection = conexao
    strsql = "SELECT codtrab, carga, origem, destino, estado, dataini FROM trabalhos where estado = 'En Route'"
    comando.CommandText = strsql
    r3 = comando.ExecuteReader
    If bs.Count = 0 Then

        bs.DataSource = r3


        ComboBox1.Text = bs.Current(0)
        tboxfunc.Text = bs.Current(1)
        TextBox1.Text = bs.Current(2)
        TextBox2.Text = bs.Current(3)
        TextBox3.Text = bs.Current(5)
        Atualizar.Enabled = True
        Cancelar.Enabled = True
        r3.Close()

        Dim sStmt1 As String = "Select codtrab from trabalhos where estado = 'En Route' "
        Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand(sStmt1, conexao)
        Dim da1 As MySqlDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd1)
        Dim dt1 As New DataTable("trabalhos")
        da1.Fill(dt1)
        If dt1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            ComboBox1.DataSource = dt1
            ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "codtrab"
        Else
            MsgBox("Não existem Funcionários", vbExclamation)
            Me.Close()
            Inicio.Show()
        End If
        da1.Dispose()
        repor()
        TextBox1.Enabled = False
        TextBox2.Enabled = False
        TextBox3.Enabled = False
        TextBox4.Enabled = False
        TextBox5.Enabled = False
        TextBox6.Enabled = False
        tboxfunc.Enabled = False
        btcancelar.Visible = False

    Else
        MsgBox("Não existem Operações En Route", vbExclamation)
        Me.Close()
        Inicio.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Mixing GUI and database operations like this is not good design. Place your database operations in a separate class, which you then call *after* you've done as much GUI work as possible. Also, be sure to call `conexao.Dispose()` when finished with all database operations.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should put the connection string in a Using block, or dispose of it manually. This usually won't cause a crash, though.
2. If Inicio is the "calling" form, you can close this form without showing Inicio.
3. Try adding an "Exit Sub" after `Me.Close`.